# Pi does not boot

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

I have 2 Raspberry Pi's and two SD cards (Arch Linux and Raspbian).

They both boot fine on the first Pi, but on the second one only the Arch Linux is booting. If I try to boot Raspbian, only the red light is on and the screen stays blank.
There are both Bs and are up to date as of August 1st.

Can someone explain this strange behavior to me?

Comment: Are you using different Rpi versions ? If yes, are you using latest arch and raspbian images ? Rpi 2 supports only latest images with kernel version 3.18.11+ or later.

Comment: No, they are both model B and the images are up to date.

Comment: One SD card makes better contact with the SD card holder pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed the problem by exchanging the SD cards against each other. Devil may care what the issue was. Thanks anyway.